# Series Expansion $\frac{1}{ 1 - e^{-x}}$ for x > 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How does one do the Expansion  $\frac{1}{ 1 - e^{-x}}$  for $x>0$ ?

I have been told that the solution is  $1 + e^{-x} + (e^{-x})^2 + (e^{-x})^3+ . . . . $.

I am having trouble seeing this directly.

I am aware of the argument that follows from the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ about x = 0 and finding the radius of convergence of the resulting series and then porting it over to the case I am asking about.

The problem is that I could forget this argument, if I do how do I straightforwardly get the correct answer without appealing to this simple arguement?

Comment: One way is to set $y=f(x)$ in $\frac1{1-f(x)}=\frac1{1-y},|y|=|f(x)|<1$

Comment: Thank you! excellent hint.